# Beginner Error with JOptionPane showmessagedialog

Tags: java, double, joptionpane

I have been following a tutorial on YouTube for Java using Eclipse.

Currently I am trying to multiply two doubles and output the result as a double using `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` but it is giving me an error.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Variables {
  public static void main(String arg[])
  {
    double length = 3;
    double width = 2;
    double area = length*width;
    JOptionPane myIO = new JOptionPane();
    myIO.showMessageDialog(null, area);
  }
}
```

and the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
  The method showMessageDialog(Component, Object) in the type JOptionPane
      is not applicable for the arguments (null, double)
    at Variables.main(Variables.java:11)
```

I have exactly what I see in the tutorial so I don't have a clue what I am doing wrong. I feel like I didn't import some library or something that I should have but it seems like Eclipse recognizes `JOptionPane` and `showMessageDialog`.

Comment: **public static void showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent,Object message)** expects a Component and an Object. You're passing a double, you probably want Double the object instead of double the primitive.

Answer (score 0):

Change your main to this:

```
 public static void main(String arg[])
      {
        double length = 3;
        double width = 2;
        double area = length*width;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, area);
      }
```

When using `JOptionPane` we do not need any declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `double area` to `Double area`.

`double` is a primitive and thus does not inherit off of `Object`, which is the parameter type `showMessageDialog` expects.

`Double` is a wrapper class for `double` and, as all objects, inherits off of `Object`.

Java often has no problem converting from `Double` to `double` and vice versa, but the fact that it takes an argument of type `Object` may imply that you didn't actually want to do what you did.

I'll note that this works in NetBeans (Java 7) and [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/EEvsmv) (Java 6) (except for an expected *runtime* error), so maybe Eclipse is in the wrong here, or you're using an old version of Java. When it comes to Java, you should always be running the latest, unless you have a specific reason not to. [Forward-compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_compatibility) is only a problem by exception.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with this code, and I would suggest reading the [official Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) rather than the one you looked at.

First of all, you shouldn't even try to run code that doesn't compile. Open the *Problems* view in Eclipse, and don't even think about running your code if there is one compilation error listed in this view.

Then read the compiler error message and try to understand them to fix them. 
The problem here is that you're probably using a very, very old version of the JDK (pre Java 5), which doesn't automatically boxes primitives (double) into their wrapper type (Double). Download the latest version of the JDK, and configure eclipse to use this new version.

But there are other problems:

- you shouldn't create a new JOptionPane to invoke the static method showMessageDialog(). Just use JOptionPane.showMessageDialog().
- you shouldn't use Swing outside of the event dispatch thread. Given that you're a newbie, don't use Swing at all, and only yse System.out.println() calls to print values on the screen for now.

Answer (score -1):

Cast an int type to the area double like so:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Variables {
    public static void main(String arg[])
    { 
        double length = 3;
        double width = 2;
        double area = length*width;
        JOptionPane myIO = new JOptionPane();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, (int)area);
    }
}
```